# Image connection time javascript

Tags: javascript, image, time, connection, loading

I played around with a bunch of images that with that are loaded from within a javascript like so:

```
albumArray[16][214] = new Image();
albumArray[16][214].src = 'dalb214.png';
```

I am replacing these with bigger sprite images to keep the http requests down, but one thing I noticed when I was playing around was that the connection time for the images loaded in javascript was much longer than that of images loaded with html in chrome dev tools.

normal image connection time: 1-3ms
javascript images: 300-350ms

this seems very strange to me to the point where I am wondering if I am doing anything wrong.

What is causing the long connection time for my javascript images and what can I do to speed it up?

Comment: Are you seeing that time for just a single image or when they are all being loaded simultaneously?

Comment: Is the browser caching the images?  Click on gear icon on bottom right of chrome dev tools and click disable cache.